# MySQL calculation big number BIGINT bypass

Tags: mysql, bigint

My application needs to handle positive numbers up to 10^45.
I have a table stats: somenumber BIGINT
In this table I have the following entry: "somenumber=775488948283"
I want MySQL to return me 775488948283000000000000000000000000000.

I tried

```
    SELECT 
    (

   SELECT somenumber FROM stats LIMIT 1

   )*1000000000000000000000000000 as bignumber;
```

But I got a MySQL error: ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT value is out of range in....

I don't understand, When I make a double select I'm not in the stats table so why MySQL is telling me it's too big, how can I just ask MySQL to multiplicate this number by 1000000000000000000000000000 and give me the result?

Answer (score 1):

When a resulting value exceeds MAX UNSIGNED range value, you can't handle it directly on whole numbers. Instead you have to use `type promotion` method on resulting value by using `cast`.

The following should work.

```
SELECT
   CAST( 
     ( SELECT my_big_int_num FROM STATS LIMIT 1 ) AS DECIMAL
   ) * 1000000000000000000000000000 as big_big_number
```

***Refer to***: [***MySQL: Out-of-Range and Overflow Handling***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you run:

```
SELECT 775488948283*1000000000000000000000000000 as bignumber;
```

You will get the right answer, but represented as a floating point number (exponential form).

If you run:

```
SELECT cast(775488948283*1000000000000000000000000000 as char(255)) as bignumber;
```

You will get the output that you want.

You can also convert the value to a string and then append the zeros:

```
select concat(cast(775488948283 as char(255)),
              '000000000000000000000000000'
             )
```

I would use the last of these.  With floating point numbers you always run the risk that the lowest order digits might turn into something else -- the precision is not enough to store 45 digits.

In the database, you might want to store the number as `decimal(65, 0)` to best represent your data.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value for BIGINT is:

```
9,223,372,036,854,775,807
```

Comment: I know but I want MySQL to return me the number*1000000000000000000000, I don't ask it to insert in the database so I don't understand why I get limited by BIGINT max value. MySQL is unable to give output numbers bigger than BIGINT max value?

Comment: Correct. `*` (multiply) is an arithmetic operator. For BIGINT, it's implemented using 64-bit registers in the machine running your MySQL server. Arbitrary-precision arithmetic classes exist in various languages, but none is built into MySQL.  You could convert your number to a string and prepend it to a bunch of zeros.

Comment: @OllieJones to be more precise not to a string but to a `varchar`